# Ruby On Rails ---- try to send error message in json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to send error messages(like following things in console when i did a wrong sql) back to frontend in json.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError (undefined local variable or method `posts' for main:Object)
```

So i wrote this in controller:

```
begin
    @results = Post.find_by_sql(params[:sql])
    if @results.first.nil?
         render json: { fail: "No such tuple"}
    else
        render json: { html: render_to_string(:template => 'all/findit') }
      end
rescue
    render json: { fails: @results.errors}
```

But from the console in browser, it still only gives a 500 error and the ajax shows "fail".
How to fix this bug? Thanks!!

Comment: Have you even considered what happens if somebody does `?sql="); DROP TABLE users;"`?

Answer (score 0):

Post::find_by_sql returns an array so you wouldn't be able to call #errors on it.

"The results will be returned as an array, with the requested columns encapsulated as attributes of the model you call this method from."

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql